# Segmentation fault on enum

Tags: swift, enums, option-type

When checking an enum value with an optional value, I get a segmentation fault.

This is wrong:

```
message?.type == .In
```

and this is right:

```
message!.type == .In // after checking for nil of course
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got it, it's trying to find .In of the type `Optional(MessageType)` (my enum), which I guess it can't as this is optional. Using `MessageType.In` instead of the syntactic sugar `.In` fixed it. (shouldn't this be an error in the editor if the compiler can't find it?)

so now I have:

```
message?.type == MessageType.In
```

which works.